# HttpClient and data output format

Tags: c#, .net, rest, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using a 3rd party web app that includes an API.

I can connect to the API, and get data via an HttpClient, but the data is not formatted correctly.

When I hit the API directly with a browser, I get nice data like this:

```
 {
  "odata.metadata":"http://ms.ischool.zzz/SOM_Rsite/Api/v1/$metadata#key","value":[
    {
      "odata.id":"http://ms.ischool.zzz/SOM_Rsite/Api/v1/key('123')","Id":"123","Name":"VideoSearch","TimeoutInMinutes":20160,"IsDefault":false,"CreateAuthTicketsForResources":false,"ReportAuthFailureAsError":false,"ExcludePrivatePresentations":true,"Internal":true,"ViewOnlyAccessContext":true
    },{
      "odata.id":"http://ms.ischool.zzz/SOM_Rsite/Api/v1/key('456')","Id":"456","Name":"DesktopRecorder","TimeoutInMinutes":20160,"IsDefault":false,"CreateAuthTicketsForResources":false,"ReportAuthFailureAsError":false,"ExcludePrivatePresentations":true,"Internal":true,"ViewOnlyAccessContext":false
    },{
      "odata.id":"http://ms.ischool.zzz/SOM_Rsite/Api/v1/key('789')","Id":"789","Name":"Manage","TimeoutInMinutes":20160,"IsDefault":false,"CreateAuthTicketsForResources":false,"ReportAuthFailureAsError":false,"ExcludePrivatePresentations":true,"Internal":true,"ViewOnlyAccessContext":false
    }
```

But when I use my HttpClient in my code, I get data like this:

```
 ["{\r\n  \"odata.metadata\":\"http://ms.ischool.zzz/SOM_Rsite/Api/v1/$metadata#key\",\"value\":[\r\n    {\r\n      \"odata.id\":\"http://ms.ischool.zzz/SOM_Rsite/Api/v1/key('123')\",\"Id\":\"123\",\"Name\":\"VideoSearch\",\"TimeoutInMinutes\":20160,\"IsDefault\":false,\"CreateAuthTicketsForResources\":false,\"ReportAuthFailureAsError\":false,\"ExcludePrivatePresentations\":true,\"Internal\":true,\"ViewOnlyAccessContext\":true\r\n    },{\r\n      \"odata.id\":\"http://ms.ischool.zzz/SOM_Rsite/Api/v1/key('456')\",\"Id\":\"456\",\"Name\":\"DesktopRecorder\",\"TimeoutInMinutes\":20160,\"IsDefault\":false,\"CreateAuthTicketsForResources\":false,\"ReportAuthFailureAsError\":false,\"ExcludePrivatePresentations\":true,\"Internal\":true,\"ViewOnlyAccessContext\":false\r\n    },{\r\n      \"odata.id\":\"http://ms.ischool.zzz/SOM_Rsite/Api/v1/key('789')\",\"Id\":\"789\",\"Name\":\"Manage\",\"TimeoutInMinutes\":20160,\"IsDefault\":false,\"CreateAuthTicketsForResources\":false,\"ReportAuthFailureAsError\":false,\"ExcludePrivatePresentations\":true,\"Internal\":true,\"ViewOnlyAccessContext\":false\r\n    }"]
```

My HttpClient code is pretty simple.  I removed the line that adds the "application/json" header, but that had no affect on the data format.

Does anyone see anything obviously wrong?

Thanks!

```
private const string URL = "http://ms.ischool.zzz/SOM_Rsite/Api/v1";

private async Task<string> GetExternalResponse()
    {
        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password");
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(URL);
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return responseBody;
    }



    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        var result = await GetExternalResponse();

        return new string[] {result};
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong, everything is fine. What you are seeing is the string representation in the Watch window of your Debugger. If you would click the little magnify icon besides it, you would get a window with the text as it would look printed.

Basically, certain characters in a string need to be escaped when declaring it in a program. The double quote is an example of that. The Debugger is displaying this escaped view of the string, i.e. the Watch window displays the string in the same way that you would need to type it if you would want to declare a variable with that value.